# ¿Cómo guardar datos de una consulta en un procedimiento almacenado desde VisualBasic.Net?

Tags: sql-server, .net, stored-procedure, vb.net

Necesito crear un Login con tipos de usuarios obligatoriamente con procedimientos almacenados en SQL Server.
No he logrado capturar el id de tipo de usuario.

Tipos de usuarios:

```
1 = Administrador
2 = Secretaria
3 = Profesional
```

El procedimiento almacenado es:

```sql
create procedure ident (@rut varchar(10), @contrasena varchar(30))
as
begin
select ID_TIPO_USUARIO from USUARIO
where RUT_USUARIO = @rut and CONTRASENA = @contrasena
end
```

Y en VisualBasic tengo lo siguiente

```vb
Dim rut, contrasena As String
rut = tbxRut.Text
contrasena = tbxContraseña.Text

Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=CONSULTORIO;" & _
"Data Source=DESKTOP-LGTPUJM\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;")

    Try
        cnn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("ident", cnn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrasena", contrasena)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try

End Using
```

El procedimiento almacenado se ejecuta sin errores, pero no se como capturar el registro de la consulta

Comment: Aparte de la pregunta, me parece que el `Try/Catch` debería ir afuera del `Using`, no es correcto usarlo adentro, ¿o estoy equivocado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta bien solo hay que modificar una cosa

```
Try
    dim Codigo integer

    cnn.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("ident", cnn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrasena", contrasena)

    Codigo = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error")
End Try
```

Comment: deberias aclarar qué es lo que hay que modificar y por qué eso resuelve el problema

Answer (score 4):

Fíjate que estás usando `ExecuteNonQuery`, lo que implica que estás ejecutando una consulta que no va a devolver un resultado.

Fácilmente puedes obtener el resultado de la consultado, utilizando por ejemplo `ExecuteScalar()`, que te va a devolver directamente `ID_TIPO_USUARIO`.

O si quieres obtener el resultado completo, deberias usar `ExecuteReader()`.

Comment: Muy atenta tu respuesta habría que preguntarle que tipo de permisos de conexión tiene. Quizás solo puede ejecutar STORE_PROCEDURES por eso no realiza efectivamente un SELECT. Si te fijas en la parte que dice "obligatoriamente con procedimientos almacenados en SQL Server."

Comment: vos decis que tiene solo permisos de ejecucion y no de lectura? raro, si puede ejecutar el SP, puede leer el resultado. Me estoy perdiendo de algo?

Comment: Creo que estás en lo cierto, ya que investigando un poco más es posible que el SP le devuelva un resultado. No lo sabía, nunca lo había intentado.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener la respuesta debes usar el

[Método SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

entonces quedaria

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("ident", cnn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrasena", contrasena)

Dim tipo As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())
```

Nota: la variable "tipo" deberias definirla por fuera del using

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría aportar una alternativa más a las muy buenas respuestas que ha tenido esta interesante pregunta.

Si deseamos usar `ExecuteNonQuery()`, podemos usar parámetros `out`, para que **SQL Server/Express** nos devuelva un resultado en dicho parámetro.

Entonces deberíamos incluir un parámetro más al procedimiento almacenado, pero especificando que se trata de un parámetro de salida (`out`):

```sql
create procedure ident (@rut varchar(10), @contrasena varchar(30), @id_tipo_usuario int out)
as
begin
select @id_tipo_usuario = ID_TIPO_USUARIO from USUARIO
where RUT_USUARIO = @rut and CONTRASENA = @contrasena
end
```

En el `SELECT` debemos asignar el resultado de la consulta al parámetro de salida: `@id_tipo_usuario = ID_TIPO_USUARIO`

Entonces el código en **VB.NET** podría ser:

```vb
Dim rut, contrasena As String
rut = tbxRut.Text
contrasena = tbxContraseña.Text

Try
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=CONSULTORIO;" & _
                                   "Data Source=DESKTOP-LGTPUJM\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                                   "Integrated Security=SSPI;")
        cnn.Open()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("ident", cnn) With {.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure}

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut", rut)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contrasena", contrasena)

            ' Agregamos el parámetro de salida para SQL Server/Express, usando la propiedad Direction.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_tipo_usuario", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            ' También se puede usar .AddWithValue(), pero quise ahorrar una variable.

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ' El resultado que devuelva el procedimiento almacenado en su parámetro de salida, se guardará en la colección Parameters.
            MsgBox("id_tipo_usuario = " & cmd.Parameters("@id_tipo_usuario").Value.ToString)
            ' Aquí se nota que tal vez sería mejor el uso de una variable.

        End Using
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
End Try
```

Como se puede ver, puse el `Try` englobando al `Using`, porque me parece que al revés es incorrecto.

Answer (score -1):

puededes poner el tu sp el `SET NOCOUNT OFF`, asi el `executeNoQuery()` te regresa la cantidad de rows afectados